# Can not direct cast or as operator a generic type to concrete type

Tags: c#, generics

See my comments in the code please, how can I get the concrete actiontype and why does the direct cast to a MyDto not work?

```
  public class Gen1Layer<TData, TAction> : GenBaseLayer<TData, TAction>
        {

            public Gen1Layer(IGenBaseLayer<TData, TAction> layer) : base(layer) { }

            public override Document<TData, TAction> ProcessDocument(Document<TData, TAction> document)
            {
                // Does not work!
                // MyDto dto = (MyDto) document.Data;

                // Does cast!
                MyDto dto1 = document.Data as MyDto;

                // Does not work!
                MyConsts.ActionType bla =  document.ActionType as MyConsts.ActionType;

                // Does not work!
                MyConsts.ActionType bla = (MyConsts.ActionType)document.ActionType;


            }
        }
```

The Gen1Layer is called this way:

```
IGenBaseLayer<MyDto,MyConsts.ActionType>  layer = new Gen1Layer<MyDto,MyConsts.ActionType>(null);
Document<MyDto,MyConsts.ActionType> doc = new Document<MyDto,MyConsts.ActionType>(new MyDto(),MyConsts.ActionType.Add,new Session());   
doc =  layer.ProcessDocument(doc);

public class Document<TData,TAction>
    {
        public Document(TData data, TAction actionType,Session session)
        {
            Data = data;
            ActionType = actionType;
            Session = session;
        }

        public TData Data { get; set; }
        public TAction ActionType { get; set; }
        public Session Session { get; set; }
    }

public class MyConsts
    {
        public enum ActionType
        { 
            Get,
            Add,
        }
    }

public interface IGenBaseLayer<TData, TAction>
    {
        Document<TData,TAction> ProcessDocument(Document<TData,TAction> document);
    }

public class GenBaseLayer<TData,TAction> : IGenBaseLayer<TData,TAction>
    {
        public GenBaseLayer(IGenBaseLayer<TData,TAction> layer)
        {
            NextLayer = layer;
        }

        public IGenBaseLayer<TData,TAction> NextLayer { get; set; }

        public virtual Document<TData,TAction> ProcessDocument(Document<TData, TAction> document)
        {
            Console.Write("Gen’s");
            return document;
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have a generic baselayer and the derived layer(s) are of the concrete type in the overriden ProcessDocument method. I know this will break polymorphism that the IGenBaseLayer will never call the ProcessDocument method of the derived layer instance. But this is what I need. Every layer can have Document with different closed generic types like CustomerDto or SupplierDto and the related CustomerActionType or SupplierActionType.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's going on here without any idea what `MyConsts` etc are. Please post a short but *complete* example.

Comment: Great you are around :P I just updated the code!

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand correctly, but can't you just do `public class Gen1Layer<TAction> : GenBaseLayer<MyDto, TAction>`? This way you have the concrete type in the concrete class.

Comment: The concrete type in the base class? why this?

Answer (score 0):

The ActionType property of MyConsts is an enumeration type, whereas ActionType property of Document is of type TAction. TAction looks like a reference type and an enumeration is more like a value type.  You can only cast reference types to another type if they inherit from that type.  You cannot cast value types to a reference type.  Your best bet is to add a getActionType() method on the Document class, process whatever TAction is, and return the corresponding enumeration. Before doing that, you should make the enumeration available to the Document class (perhaps define it outside of the MyConsts class?).

Comment: I can not put the enumeration into the document class. The Document class must be generic for Data and ActionType.

Comment: @Pascal: If it's meant to be generic, then how do you expect to be able to cast to `MyConsts.ActionType`?

Comment: @Jon well the problem is that in the derived class all the generic types are open generics if they would be closed that would be fine, but then as I wrote above the polymorphism does not work anymore. If I would use a Document with Data of type Object and ActionType of type Object I am not forced to use generics for all the layers but object should be avoided actually...

Comment: I replaced now all the TData and TAction with type object and all works fine, but Data and Actiontype are reference + value type so there is a cast and boxing/unboxing what I wanted to avoid with generics. But it seems my idea does not work.

Answer (score 0):

While what you are doing seems a bit sketchy

```
MyConsts.ActionType bla = (MyConsts.ActionType)Enum.
    ToObject(typeof(MyConsts.ActionType), System.Convert.ToInt32(document.ActionType));
```

will accomplish what you are after at the expense of type safety.